Is it possible to dynamically change a cell/column reference in an excell formula based on another cell
Good morning, I have a spreadsheet with lots of columns of dates, where I compare three columns to give me a Y, N or 2 answer.
=IF($D9="","",IF(AND($D9=$JV$2,NOT(ISBLANK(BK9)),NOT(ISBLANK(JJ9)),NOT(ISBLANK($AT9)),BK9\<=JJ9,BK9\<=$AT9),"N",IF(AND($D9=$JV$2,NOT(ISBLANK(BK9)),NOT(ISBLANK(JJ9)),NOT(ISBLANK($AT9)),$AT9\<=JJ9),2,IF(AND($D9=$JV$2,NOT(ISBLANK(BK9)),NOT(ISBLANK(JJ9)),NOT(ISBLANK($AT9)),BK9\>JJ9,$AT9\>JJ9),"Y",""))))

The spreadsheet has a few hundred rows.
Is it possible to have the formula change the column reference for columns JJ and BK change depending what I select from drop down boxes, one for Column JJ and one for column BK?
Thanks you.
I have tried INDIRECT without any success.

You've tried INDIRECT without success. What was your attempt? What logic are you after? Because answering your question would simply be "yes"

Let's assume bkref is the name for the column BK reference (the value should be the letter name of the column) and jjref is the name for the column JJ reference. I simplified the formula at the same time.
=LET(
  BK_,INDIRECT(bkref&ROW()),
  JJ_,INDIRECT(jjref&ROW()),
  IFS(
    OR($D9="",ISBLANK(BK_),ISBLANK(JJ_),ISBLANK($AT9),$D9<>$JV$2),"",
    AND(BK_<=JJ_,BK_<=$AT9),"N",
    $AT9<=JJ_,2,
    AND(BK_>JJ_,$AT9>JJ_),"Y",
    TRUE,""
  )
)

Since BK is in the cell JY2 and JJ is in the cell JZ2 (for Microsoft 365):
=LET(
  BK_,INDIRECT($JV$2&ROW()),
  JJ_,INDIRECT($JZ$2&ROW()),
  IFS(
    OR($D9="",ISBLANK(BK_),ISBLANK(JJ_),ISBLANK($AT9),$D9<>$JV$2),"",
    AND(BK_<=JJ_,BK_<=$AT9),"N",
    $AT9<=JJ_,2,
    AND(BK_>JJ_,$AT9>JJ_),"Y",
    TRUE,""
  )
)


For Excel 2019 and above:
=IFS(
  OR($D9="",ISBLANK(INDIRECT($JV$2&ROW())),ISBLANK(INDIRECT($JZ$2&ROW())),ISBLANK($AT9),$D9<>$JV$2),"",
  AND(INDIRECT($JV$2&ROW())<=INDIRECT($JZ$2&ROW()),INDIRECT($JV$2&ROW())<=$AT9),"N",
  $AT9<=INDIRECT($JZ$2&ROW()),2,
  AND(INDIRECT($JV$2&ROW()),$AT9>INDIRECT($JZ$2&ROW())),"Y",
  TRUE,""
)


For Excel versions below 2019:
=IF(
  OR($D9="",ISBLANK(INDIRECT($JV$2&ROW())),ISBLANK(INDIRECT($JZ$2&ROW())),ISBLANK($AT9),$D9<>$JV$2),
  "",
  IF(
    AND(INDIRECT($JV$2&ROW())<=INDIRECT($JZ$2&ROW()),INDIRECT($JV$2&ROW())<=$AT9),
    "N",
    IF(
      $AT9<=INDIRECT($JZ$2&ROW()),
      2,
      IF(
        AND(INDIRECT($JV$2&ROW()),$AT9>INDIRECT($JZ$2&ROW())),
        "Y",
        ""
      )
    )
  )
)

